# Supabase two level of joins in typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, supabase

I've read the documentation [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/joins-and-nesting), and I kind of got this working on the first level (agent_profile), but when I try to join the next level (agent_office) I run into trouble. The query works, I manage to get the right data back. But VS Code and when I run my app it doesn't recognize the agent_office as a parameter on the agent profile. Any ideas how I can solve this?

```
const realestateWithAgentProfileAndAgentOfficeQuery = supabase.from('realestate')
supabase.from('realestate')  

.select('\*,agent_profile(\*, agent_office(*)))')  
.limit(1)

type RealEstateWithAgentQuotes = QueryData<typeof realestateWithAgentProfileAndAgentOfficeQuery>
```

And my state object:

```
  const [realEstate, setRealEstate] = useState<RealEstateWithAgentQuotes>()
```

And as I said, the data is there when I print it to the console. But when trying to access it.

```
{(realEstate.agent_profile.map((quote: AgentProfile) => (
```

And then it fails here

```
{quote.agent_office}
```

> 'agent_office' does not exist on type '{......

Comment: remember to `await` the result from the `realestateWithAgentProfileAndAgentOfficeQuery` promise. Also remember to deconstruct the `data` property from the query result. Here's an example: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select#response-types-for-complex-queries

Comment: Also make sure you have regenerated the types since `agent_office` was added as a foreign key on `agent_profile`: eg. via the CLI `supabase gen types typescript --project-id abcdefghijklmnopqrst > database.types.ts`

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is this line:
`(realEstate.agent_profile.map((quote: AgentProfile) => (` maybe remove the type here `AgentProfile` because TypeScript should be able to infer the type from `RealEstateWithAgentQuotes`, which will be the correct type for your database schema.

Comment: There's a scenario where the join is ambigious with multiple tables (many to many relationships). This could be the case with your schema, but I think you would need to share it in your question for us to see. Here's how to explicitly define the join column table in the query when the join column is ambigious:
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/joins-and-nesting#specifying-the-on-clause-for-joins-with-multiple-foreign-keys

Comment: @RobertRendell lets start with this one, if I remove  `: AgentProfile` I get the error `Parameter 'quote' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`
And that was the only solution I found to my problem

Comment: @RobertRendell I think I have narrowed it down to this. But please enlighten me if I am off,
`type RealEstateWithAgentQuotes = QueryData<typeof realestateWithAgentProfileAndAgentOfficeQuery>;`

When I hover this in VS Code is says
`type RealEstateWithAgentQuotesAgentProfile = any`

Which doesn't seem right.
When looking at this YT video he gets the full description at 11m:14s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCoRxQsHgrE

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I was missing the database type when initing supabase

```
const supabase = createClientComponentClient<Database>()
```